# Unexpected identifier 'hs_post'

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

I'm implementing some code from unity into my school project to add server sided highscores.
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

However my browser is returning this error - 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'hs_post'

URL of my project
https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~osengam001/grijptitus/

Snippet from my JS file

```
var secretKey = "jonathantitus"; // Edit this value and make sure it's the same as the one stored on the server
var addScoreUrl = "https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~osengam001/grijptitus/php/addscore.php?"; //be sure to add a ? to your url
var highscoreUrl = "https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~osengam001/grijptitus/php/display.php";

function postScore(username, score) {
    //This connects to a server side php script that will add the name and score to a MySQL DB.
    // Supply it with a string representing the players name and the players score.
    var hash = Md5.Md5Sum(username + titusGevangen + secretKey);

    var highscore_url = addScoreUrl + "name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(username) + "&score=" + titusGevangen + "&hash=" + hash;

    // Post the URL to the site and create a download object to get the result.
    hs_post = WWW(highscore_url);
    yield hs_post; // Wait until the download is done
    if (hs_post.error) {
        print("There was an error posting the high score: " + hs_post.error);
    }
}

// Get the scores from the MySQL DB to display in a GUIText.
function getScores() {
    gameObject.guiText.text = "Loading Scores";
    hs_get = WWW(highscoreUrl);
    yield hs_get;

    if (hs_get.error) {
        print("There was an error getting the high score: " + hs_get.error);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("beginTekst").innerHTML = hs_get.text; // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
    }
}
```

Comment: That error message means the parser doesn't recognize `yield`. What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried both Safari and Chrome and they give me the same error.

Comment: Only Firefox supports `yield` in a function defined using `function`. ES6 requires [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks melpomene.
Only Firefox supports yield in a function defined using function. ES6 requires [function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A).